# Как скачать пакеты для конкретной версии Python? (cp38-cp39)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Есть комп без инета, и инет там никогда и не будет, там стоит `python3.8`.
На компе с интернетом `python3.9` и соответсенно через `pip download` скачивает пакеты `cp39` для `python3.9`.

Есть ли способ через `pip download` скачать cp38?
Например, `pip download numpy --platform` или `cp38`

Comment: Дайте знать о результате и о ваших ОС, если разберетесь с ошибкой. Может оформить как "Ответ на собственный вопрос".

Answer (score 3):

Для этого есть переключатели `--python-version`(версия python),`--platform`(аппаратная платформа), `--implementation`(реализация python)

Когда эти переключатели не указаны - pip скачивает пакеты для текущей версии.

Соответственно, что бы скачать пакет numpy для python 3.8, достаточно указать:

```
pip download --python-version 3.8 numpy
```

Comment: ERROR: When restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version, --platform, --abi, or --implementation, either --no-deps must be set, or --only-binary=:all: must be set and --no-binary must not be set (or must be set to :none:).

Comment: @legion088 гляньте [сюда](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/). Это дока для `pip download`

Answer (score 2):

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 38 --implementation cp numpy

pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 38 --implementation cp numpy --dest F:\pack
```

Второй вариант сразу на флешку!

Comment: Есть комментарии почему так? и из-за чего ошибка вылетала? В любом случае +